# PostgreSQL greener: syntax error at or near "extract"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a greener on writing PostgreSQL. I wrote a simple function and it yielded error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks a lot!

```sql
create or replace function constellation(birthday date)
returns varchar(8)
begin atomic
return (if extract(month from birthday)=12 then '摩羯')
end
```

```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "extract"
LINE 4: return (if extract(month from birthday)=12 then '摩羯')
                   ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 100
```

=====
Updates: I've also tried `case` method, and it still raied error:

```sql
create or replace function constellation(birthday date)
returns varchar(8)
begin atomic
return (case when extract(month from birthday)=12 then '摩羯')
end
```

```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 4: ...turn (case when extract(month from birthday)=12 then '摩羯')
                                                                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 148
```

Comment: Use a case expression instead of if. And what should be returned for month 1 to 11?

Comment: You can't use `IF` in SQL - only in PL/pgSQL. In SQL you need to use a CASE expression. If you want to convert a date to a month name, why not use `to_char(birthday, 'TMMonth')` - if your locale is set correctly, that should return  the name in your locale's language.

Comment: @jarlh This is a just a trivial try and I plan to add those months. However it has already failed even with only one case... Actually I've also tried ```case``` method but it raised the same error.

Comment: You could try the manual first: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: Perhaps you need a national character string literal, `N'摩羯'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a function with a SQL language body. SQL has no `IF` statement, so you need to use a SELECT statement that uses a CASE expression:

```
create or replace function constellation(birthday date)
returns varchar(8)
begin atomic
 select case 
          when extract(month from birthday) = 12 
               and extract(day from birthday)<=21 then '摩羯'
          when extract(month from birthday) = 11 then 'eleven'
          when extract(month from birthday) = 10 then 'ten'
          else 'No idea'
        end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! How about if I'd like more complicated conditions such as ```extract(month from birthday)=12 and extract(day from birthday)<=21```? then it is not suitable to write ```extract(month from birthday)``` right after ```case```...

Comment: (Continued) Like this:

```select case birthday
when extract (day from birthday)=12 then '摩羯'```

It tells me that

```ERROR:  operator does not exist: date = boolean
LINE 5: when extract (day from birthday)=12 then '摩羯'
        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 110```

Comment: @atlantic0cean: see my edit. For more details on the syntax of the CASE expression, please [see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not specifically require a `from` clause on `select`, but even without it you can still include a `where` clause (unusual but doable). This permits reducing to a single statement and without the case expression by putting the relational operators in the `where` clause. Also, as only a SQL it reduces to a sql function: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ed405bc7cb7703fa7d4ed82167e830e8))

```
create or replace function constellation(birthdate date)
  returns varchar
  language sql 
as $$
  select '摩羯'
   where extract(month from birthdate) = 12 
     and extract(month from birthdate) <= 21 
$$;
```